# How to select Multiple Rows based on one Column

Tags: sql, arrays, sqlite

So I have looked around the internet, and couldn't find anything that could be related to my issue.

This is part of my DB:

```
ID  |     English    |    Pun    |  SID   |  Writer   |
=======================================================
1   |      stuff     |   stuff   |   1    |   Full    |
2   |      stuff     |   stuff   |   1    |   Rec.    |
3   |      stuff     |   stuff   |   2    |   Full    |
4   |      stuff     |   stuff   |   2    |   Rec.    |
```

Now how would I get all rows with SID being equal to 1.

Like this

```
ID  |     English    |    Pun    |  SID   |  Writer   |
=======================================================
1   |      stuff     |   stuff   |   1    |   Full    |
2   |      stuff     |   stuff   |   1    |   Rec.    |
```

Or when I want to get all rows with SID being equal to 2.

```
ID  |     English    |    Pun    |  SID   |  Writer   |
=======================================================
3   |      stuff     |   stuff   |   2    |   Full    |
4   |      stuff     |   stuff   |   2    |   Rec.    |
```

This is my current SQL Query using SQLite:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE SID = 1
```

And I only get the first row, how would I be able to get all of the rows?

Here is my PHP Code:

```
class GurDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('gurbani.db3');
    }
}

$db = new GurDB();
$mode = $_GET["mode"];

if($mode == "2") {
    $shabadnum = $_GET["shabadNo"];
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE SID = $shabadnum");
    $array = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    print_r($array);
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting invalid column `1` error

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table` where sid = 1 .

Comment: You don't need the quotes around the column name ('SID'). And you only need them around the value (1) if it's a VarChar; but it looks like it could be an int. If so: get rid of all those quotes (including the table name, if you're enclosing that in quotes).

Comment: @B.ClayShannon That's a back tick and it is for reserved words, a string should be wrapped with a singel quote mark '

Comment: You shouldn't have your table name in any sort of symbol like that. See sagi's comment. Your table name is not a reserved word, or shouldn't be; that would be asking for trouble, or at least confusion.

Comment: @sagi I fixed up the query, I wasn't paying attention. How can I get all rows though, I only get the first one.

Comment: The SQL is fine. Show your code!

Comment: You would get all the rows where SID has a value of 2 with that query.

Comment: @CL Added the PHP Code, it should be working fine, but the array spits out 1 row.

Comment: @Hogan https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php It's not `print_r`

Comment: @Hogan, I knew something was up with `fetchArray`. Anyone here give me an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch array only gives you one row... you want something like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```